# Why does docker-compose up get stuck starting when I give the container access to my GPU?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following docker setup:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu

WORKDIR /project
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libgl1-mesa-glx
RUN apt-get install libxcb-xinerama0

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT ["python", "scripts/test.py"]
```

docker-compose.yaml:

```
services:
  app:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/project
    #deploy:
    #  resources:
    #    reservations:
    #      devices:
    #      - capabilities: [gpu]
```

The entry point of the Dockerfile (test.py) is just an infinite loop so the container will keep running. Using this, I call `docker-compose build`, `docker-compose up -d`, then `docker-compose exec app bash` to get an interactive shell where I can call the scripts in my project. This works, but my problem comes when I uncomment everything everything below deploy in the docker-compose file, in order to give the container access to my gpu. When I do this and then try to repeat the same series of commands, `docker-compose up -d` gets stuck starting the container.

```
[+] Running 1/2
 ⠿ Network pose-estimation-tests_default  Created                                                                                              
 ⠿ Container pose-estimation-tests-app-1  Starting
```

As far as I can tell, it never moves past this point.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the `runtime` in your compose? (e.g. `runtime: nvidia` and also maybe the `NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=all` env var). Can you share some more detailed logs too (use the `docker-compose logs` command)

Comment: @Lissy93 I tried adding `runtime: nvidia` under resources and got the following error after trying to build: `services.app.deploy Additional property runtime is not allowed`. Adding `NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=all` as an env var in the Dockerfile doesn't seem to do anything. `docker-compose logs` also doesn't seem to output anything if I run it after `docker-compose up -d`, and I have to ctrl+c out of it.

Comment: I think the error from adding `runtime: nvidia` was due to some weird indentation. I played around with it and got it to build with the runtime specified. Then when I `docker-compose up -d` I get this error: `Error response from daemon: Unknown runtime specified nvidia`.

Comment: Sorry, should have said that I just used Nvidia as an example - you'd need to put your actual GPU runtime info in there.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was a known issue with Docker (https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/13324), and similar behavior is exhibited when trying to use the `--gpus` option from `docker run`. I fixed it by upgrading to Docker 4.18.0.